# ios navigate and display data in tableview on another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view with a `textbox`, `pickerview` and `UIButton`(working as radio buttons).
On click of submit `UIButton`, the user should be shown with the details entered by him on another view having a `tableView`. I am using `navigationController` to navigate on another view with `tableview`.
The navigation works fine but how do I display the data entered in `view1` on `view2` that too in tableview?
Following is my code:
.m

```
- (void) goToViewTwo
{
   tableViewController *viewTwo = [[tableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   self.tabView = viewTwo;

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabView animated:YES]; 
}
```

How do I assign the data to tabView?

**edited to include .h of tableViwController**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *lbl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabal;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you're doing it, except before pushing the next view controller, set a property on it.  For example, to show the text from viewOne on viewTwo, viewTwo will need a string property called (something like) textFromViewOne.

```
tableViewController *viewTwo = [[tableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// assume this vc has an outlet to it's text field called viewOneTextField
viewTwo.textFromViewOne = viewOneTextField.text;

// not sure why you're saving a ref to this new vc, when do you use it?
self.tabView = viewTwo;

// you don't need it here    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewTwo animated:YES];
```

Now, in the second VC, it can contain UIControls to present the data stored in it's properties.  Continuing with the text example...

```
// assume you know how to create properties on the "tableViewController" class (not a great name, btw)

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // assume you have a label called label
    label.text = self.textFromViewOne;
}
```

Comment: heh, we all had the same answer, that's a good thing i guess :p

Comment: i tried it and i get this error:
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RegFlowAppDelegate class]));     Thread1: Program received signal:"SIGABR"

Comment: in view2 i created a label and synthesized it. Then in view2.m i wrote: //the animated method wasn't there, i created it.
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    textLabel.text = self.name;
}

Comment: hmm.  well, i left out the call to super.  it's possible that's the error.  edited the answer.  please give that a try.  also, set an exception breakpoint (go to breakpoints navigator, + button on lower left).  Then xcode will stop nearer to the source line that's causing the failure.

Comment: tried it, still the same. I even removed the animated method and still the error occurs. I debugged the code, the error comes while executing the following line: [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabView animated:YES]; with is in the method SubmitClick() shown in my question

Comment: okay.  two things, first push the variable viewTwo.  I can't see any reason to assign it to a property.  Next, is viewTwo a valid subclass of UIViewController?  Try this:  NSLog(@"vc is %@, it's class is %@", viewTwo, viewTwo.class);

Comment: when i logged it, it said that "viewTwo is a class of tableViewController".

Comment: Can you post that class's .h file?

Comment: sorry i can't be of further help.  the problem you're having seems to be unrelated to passing a string between the vcs, which is what was asked answered here.  crashing when you push the new vc and the error msg seems indicative of a problem with the setup on the storyboard.

Comment: i am not using storyboard.

Comment: hey i guess there was something wrong with the nib name, i recreated the xib file of tableViewController and followed your answer, it worked! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use properties @property feature.

Like in view2.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name;
```

in view2.m

```
@synthesize name;
```

in your view1.m

```
  - (void) goToViewTwo
{

    tableViewController *viewTwo = [[tableViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.tabView = viewTwo;
    viewTwo.name=textbox.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabView animated:YES];

}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: agree +1.  same comment as the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need some properties set on tableViewController. So if you were passing a string through. tableViewController would have the following in the .h file.

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mystring;
```

You would synthesize this string as well in the .m file.

```
@synthesize mystring;
```

Then you can call in the above code

```
viewTwo.mystring = @"some value to pass through";
```

Which then allows you to access the value you passed through in the tableViewController by calling self.mystring. Hope that helps some.

Comment: agree +1.  that + using the property in view will appear is correct imo

Answer (score 0):

In the tabView.h class create receiver method

-(init) GetData:(NSString *)textboxString picker:(NSString *)pickerValue;

create the Intance variable to receive data

NSString *str1
NSString *str2

In the tabView.m

```
-(init) GetData:(NSString *)textboxString picker:(NSString *)pickerValue
{
     str1 = [textboxString copy];
     str2 = [pickerValue copy];

     return self;
}
```

now in -(void) goToViewTwo method

call your method which you created in the tabtwo class

```
[viewTwo init:textboxString picker:pickerValue];
```